# jquery calling function on parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery on an html page to load another page into a div, using .ajax().
The second page has a form. when that form submits, I want to call a function (located on the initial page). Currently I get this "ReferenceError: getHistory is not defined" (where 'getHistory is the name of the function).

MAIN PAGE (reduced for space) - object: click button, form appears, submit form, history is updated from ajax call.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>...</head>
<body>

    <div id="msg"></div>

    <input type="button" id="AddEvent" value="add" />

    <div id="addForm"></div>

    <div id="history"></div>

    <!-- script references -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

    <script>
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            // Show form
            $( '#AddEvent' ).click( function() {
                $( '#addForm' ).hide();
                $( '#addForm' ).load( 'addform.html', function( response, status, xhr ) {
                    $( '#addForm' ).slideDown( 1000 ).fadeIn( 3000 );
                    if ( status == 'error' ) {
                        var msg = 'Sorry but there was an error loading the form: ';
                        $( '#msg' ).html( msg + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText );
                    } 
                });
            });

            // function to populate history
            function getHistory() {
                ...AJAX to populate history div...
            }

            // initial load on page load
            getHistory();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

FORM PAGE: (reduced for space).

```
<form role="form" id="eventform" action="/eventHandeler" method="post" >
    ...
</form>
<script>
$( document ).ready( function() {

    $( '#eventform' ).ajaxForm( function() {

        alert("Thank you for add!");

        // ****** THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO RELOAD THE HISTORY...function on parent page
        getHistory();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created the function `getHistory` in a closure scope(inside the dom ready handler) so it won't be accessible outside of that closure scope. If you want to make it accessible outside you need to declare it in a a scope shared by both the calling methods(in this case the global scope)

Move the method to global scope

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Show form
    $('#AddEvent').click(function () {
        $('#addForm').hide();
        $('#addForm').load('addform.html', function (response, status, xhr) {
            $('#addForm').slideDown(1000).fadeIn(3000);
            if (status == 'error') {
                var msg = 'Sorry but there was an error loading the form: ';
                $('#msg').html(msg + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    });


    // initial load on page load
    getHistory();
})

//move it to global scope from the closure scope
// function to populate history
function getHistory() {
    //...AJAX to populate history div...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use parent to refer the parent frame and then like below we can execute the function.
in this case it can be :

```
parent.getHistory()
```

But to use the function like above we need to bring the definition of function out of document ready, to give it more scope. And then by above way we can access.

Comment: by moving the function to the global scope - "parent." was not needed. But thank you.